# Using ResultSet to compare result within IF Statement (JAVA)

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have this piece of code where I prompt the user to enter the depID to edit a department and then through the IF statement I have done it displays either saved or department doesn't exists.  Now my problem is that it's going directly to the else statement.  When I used debugging I noticed that the RS (ResultSet) is only comaring the users input to the first row of the table which is AOL.

```
      try{
         String value1 = txt_depID.getText();
         String value2 = txt_depName.getText();

        String sql = "Update tblDepartment set depID = '"+value1+"' ,    depName = '"+value2+"' where depID = '"+value1+"'";
        String sql1 = "Select depID, depName from tblDepartment";
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.execute();


        if(rs.next()){
            String depi = rs.getString("depID"); //Issue: only reading first row

            if(depi.equals(value1)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry Saved");
           }

           else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Department doesn't exist");
           }
        }           
     } catch (Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
```

Comment: There is no way a String `staffnum` will equal the ResultSet `rs`. You should be checking `staffnum` against some other value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one cycle. You should be using `executeUpdate`.

```
String sql = "Delete from tblEmployee where staffNo=?";
String sql1 = "Select * from tblEmployee";
Class.forName(driver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
if (result > 0) {
   // success
}
```

Here's what executeUpdate results:

> Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language
>   (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing